# RST: how to decrease font size in code blocks?

Tags: restructuredtext, rst2pdf

I would like to include a code block in a presentation I am preparing with Restructured Text. But the font used in the code block is huge and it can not fit inside resulting code box:

[image]

How can I reduce the font size used in code blocks?

Comment: What tool do you use to generate output?

Comment: I am using `rst2pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `fontSize` property of the `code` style in your style file.

e.g.

```
code:
    parent: literal
    fontSize: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the builtin themes (*alabaster*) accept usage of `custom.css`.

Create `_static/custom.css` and add the following to adjust the `code-block` font-size:

*_static/custom.css*:

```
.highlight { background: #f8f8f8; font-size: x-small;}
```

Comment: The names have changed a bit: `div.highlight {background-color: {{ theme_code_highlight_bg }}; font-size: x-small;}`, see https://github.com/bitprophet/alabaster/blob/master/alabaster/static/alabaster.css_t

Answer (score 0):

You need a layout.html in a dir `mysources/_templates` and in your `mysources/conf.py` you need a declaration `templates_path = ['_templates']`.

In layout.html add a declaration

```
div.highlight {
    font-size  : 0.8em; /* or another value you prefer */
}
```

This works for me because I use the html_theme *sphinxdoc*. Maybe in other themes the declarations differ. If so you must find out the declaration by a html debugger like *Inspektor* in Firefox or Developer Tools in Chrome or DOM Explorer in IE.

Comment: Sorry, I just did not see that you use rst2pdf. My tool is Sphinx. Hope, that my answer gives you a hint anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a file called `style_code_font_size.yaml` in your docs root with this content:

```yaml
styles:
    code:
        parent: literal
        fontSize: 8
```

If you are using Sphinx, prepend this new style to `pdf_stylesheets` in `conf.py`:

```py
pdf_stylesheets = ["twocolumn", "sphinx"]
```

```py
pdf_stylesheets = ["style_code_font_size", "twocolumn", "sphinx"]
```